# Need help to parse my custom CLI commands

Tags: c, parsing, command-line-interface, lexer

I'm developing a custom CLI in C. The CLI commands are something like:

```
debug read card 6 block 5 size 10
system update remote sftp://... password ****
copylogs card.log system.log module.log
system reload warm module1
```

The commands are in different lengths and may include optional fields.

Now I have two questions.

1- What should I bear in mind when finalizing the shape/grammer of the commands, in order not to get into trouble when lexing/parsing.

2- What is the best practice to parse the commands. I searched around the net and it seems the flex-bson way is the way I should go. As I'm totally new to these kinds of things, I'm here to get help. What should I do? Should I write my custom lexer/parser? Should I go the flex-bson way? Is there a ready-to-use lexer/parser that I can directly use in my code?

Your help is appreciated...

Comment: You could use the "standard C" way of handling arguments, and pass each function a counter and an array of strings, and let each "command" parse the arguments on their own.

Comment: What I did long ago was, I looked into `openssl` code source to see what they did and try to adapt it to mine. So basically, all arguments are saved in an array of strings `argv`. You compare each item with your predefined flag. If it corresponds, then the next item should be the value......

Comment: @someprogrammerdude thanks for your comment. Any comment on using the flex-bison strategy?

Comment: Nothing specific. It's one way to solve your problem. And a very powerful and flexible way, which of course brings with it quote some complexity. If you should use it really depends on the format of the commands and their argument, the more "natural" they are the more complex the solutions have to be. What you show is quite complex structure and will probably be well-suited for a Lex-Yacc (or Flex-Bison) solution.

Comment: @PhoenixBlue Thanks. So you say it's an standard strategy to go this way. By the way what's your idea of the flex-bison strategy. It fits for this case? It worths the pain?

Comment: @Mahdi.B I do similar thing. Do you have some implementation or design to share?